# Как занести ip-адресс в MySQL с помощью RedBeanPHP

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, redbeanphp

Я работаю с помощью redbeanphp.И при размещении данных посылаемых от формы,все добавляется.Но при записи ip выдает ошибку:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught [42S22] - SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'ip' in 'field list' trace: #0 C:\OpenServer\domains\receptach\rb-mysql.php(1175): RedBeanPHP\Driver\RPDO->runQuery('INSERT INTO `us...', Array) #1 C:\OpenServer\domains\receptach\rb-mysql.php(1215): RedBeanPHP\Driver\RPDO->GetAll('INSERT INTO `us...', Array) #2 C:\OpenServer\domains\receptach\rb-mysql.php(4390): RedBeanPHP\Driver\RPDO->GetOne('INSERT INTO `us...', Array) #3 C:\OpenServer\domains\receptach\rb-mysql.php(6138): RedBeanPHP\Adapter\DBAdapter->getCell('INSERT INTO `us...', Array, 0) #4 C:\OpenServer\domains\receptach\rb-mysql.php(6265): RedBeanPHP\QueryWriter\AQueryWriter->insertRecord('users', Array, Array) #5 C:\OpenServer\domains\receptach\rb-mysql.php(9086): RedBeanPHP\QueryWriter\AQueryWriter->updateRecord('users', Array, 0) #6 C:\OpenServer\domains\receptach\rb-mysql.php(8453): RedBeanPHP\Repository\Frozen->storeBean(Object(RedBeanPHP\OODBBean)) #7 C:\OpenServer\domains\receptach\rb-mysql.php(9563): RedBeanPHP\Reposito in C:\OpenServer\domains\receptach\rb-mysql.php on line 838
```

Вот сам код:

```
$user = R::dispense('users');
        $user->email = $_POST['email'];
        $user->password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        $user->ip = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
        R::store($user);
```

Если убрать эту строчку:

```
$user->ip = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
```

То все работает нормально,и введённые данные заносятся в бд без ошибок.В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Правильный ответ такой:

```
$user->ip = $_POST['$ip']; //тут переменная которая получает ip
```

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте создать в бд поле ip :)